# Google Earth transparent weather KML file overlay

Tags: kml, google-earth, transparency-opacity

I am unable to make any of the weather overlays from the website below transparent/opaque once they are loaded into Google Earth.

I have attempted to modify the KML file directly by using the  attribute inside of the Screen Overlay tag but this did not work.

Is there any way of making the overlay transparent before it renders to the screen?

https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/kmzgenerator.php

Comment: Are you using Google Earth Pro, or the new Google Earth for web, Android & iOS? In Earth Pro, you should be able to adjust transparency with the slider at the bottom of the Places panel.  In new Earth, you'll need to edit the KML... which should work if it's a static KML, but not if it's dynamically loading (eg: a NetworkLink).  Can you share your KML, or a sample that shows how you tried to modify it, so we can help debug? You say that you modified the "ScreenOverlay", which will only change the logos (top of screen)...  to make the data transparent, you'll need to edit the "GroundOverlay".